# Appropiate way to color DataGridView rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there a best practice way to color rows based on row data? I currently have this:

```
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Finally Add DataTable into DataGridView
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Columns["File_Name"].Width = 240;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Create_Date"].Width = 130;
            //dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Create_Date"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < unreadList.Count; y++)
            {
                if ( unreadList[y] == 1 )
                    dataGridView1.Rows[y].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
            }
        }
```

To clarify, `unreadList` is an array where a `1` represents that index matched some string on that row index.

But when `RowFilter` is used etc, the colors vanish. Is there anything to handle this, including if the columns are sorted? My index method will not work after a sort either.

Comment: Was my answer not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do your coloring in the CellFormatting/RowPostPaint events to keep coloring after a filter/sort.

```
private void gridView_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < unreadList.Count; y++)
    {
        if (unreadList[y] == 1)
            dataGridView1.Rows[y].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
    }
}

private void gridItems_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellStyle.BackColor != Color.LightPink) //This will color every other row green - as an example.
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
}
```